# VBA Loop and Setting Variable

Tags: vba, loops, variables

I'm currently using a loop with a variable that changes based on a a list. The loop creates new worksheets and names them based on the current value of the variable "c".

I would like to introduce another variable "b" and have it represent the same row as "c" is on but a different column. I also want to "b" to then write it's value to a specific cell on the new worksheet. I

I have not been able to figure out how to introduce a second variable and have it loop it's own list within the already running loop.

Here is the current code:

```
Sub CopyIndTemplate()
Dim sh1 As Worksheet, sh2 As Worksheet, c As Range
Set sh1 = Sheets("Individual Template")
Set sh2 = Sheets("List")
    
    
    For Each c In sh2.Range("b1", sh2.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp))
        sh1.Copy After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
        ActiveSheet.Name = c.Value: ActiveSheet.Range("A1") = c.Value: ActiveSheet.Range("b9") = b.Value
            
    Next   
End Sub
```

Comment: use an [offset](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.offset)

Comment: `b` might be `c.EntireRow.Cells(5)` or  `c.EntireRow.Columns("H")` for example

Comment: Side note, consider forgetting that the `:` token exists, and having one single instruction per line of code. Makes things much easier to debug, you can't place a breakpoint in the middle of a line to inspect intermediate state. Also consider using actual descriptive names for your variables, e.g. `TemplateSheet` instead of `sh1`, `ListSheet` instead of `sh2`, `currentCell` instead of `c`, `sourceCell` instead of `b` (and declare it, and make sure the module says `Option Explicit` at the top). Rule of thumb, avoid single-letter names.

Comment: *have it represent the same row as "c" is on but a different column* - cool, *which* column?

Comment: Thank you @TimWilliams, your suggestion worked perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

`c` represents the current cell in column B.

If you want to get the cell in the same row but in column C, you can do `c.Offset(ColumnOffset:=1)`, and to get the cell in the same row but in column A, you can do `c.Offset(ColumnOffset:=-1)`.

`Range.Offset` often makes for extremely confusing and hard-to-follow code when [mis]used with `ActiveCell` in loops, but when you want your code to convey that you mean to get a cell that's *offset* from the cell you're currently looking at, using it makes code that conveys *intent*, and that's the one single thing you want your code to do: do what it says, and say what it does.